# How to call inchoo social connect login in one page checkout page magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, magento-1.9.1

I used  inchoo social login plugin from this url:

```
http://inchoo.net/magento/facebook-connect-magento-extension/
```

But it will show social login buttons in login and registration page only.

I want to show social login buttons in one page checkout page as well. I tried but unable to do that.

If anyone have any idea to resolve this problem, then please help me put.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your checkout page phtml in which you want to call these buttons, add following code:

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('inchoo_socialconnect/google_button')->setTemplate("inchoo/socialconnect/google/button.phtml")->toHtml();
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('inchoo_socialconnect/facebook_button')->setTemplate("inchoo/socialconnect/facebook/button.phtml")->toHtml();
```

Comment: You are awsome! Thanks